# Itunes remote api for android

Tags: android, itunes

I want to control Itunes on my computer with my android phone. Is there any api or webservice I can connect with? I just want to pause or unpause itunes from an android app.

Comment: You have many applications in the Play Store that do that like Remote for iTunes, Retune or iRemote...

Comment: I know, but I want to use in my own app.

Comment: Well, so I provided you with some source code that you can use, which you already accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the many applications already provided in Google Play for what you want. If you are looking to develop this kind of application yourself, then you can take a look here:

http://dacp.jsharkey.org/

And the code that he is provided could be found here:

https://code.google.com/p/android-cookbook/source/browse/#svn/trunk/TunesControl